# Sourcing vintage style pedals

Tags: pedals

Looking for a replacement set of pedals for the image shown below (EU/DE). Came off a Diamant Rennrad, not an expensive bike but would like to keep the styling similar to the original. I've seen a couple for sale on ebay (40-50 euros), **but wondering if anyone has some other sources for old style pedals?**

[image]

Comment: https://velo-orange.com/collections/pedals

Comment: I suspect this question will be closed as Shopping, please don't take it personally.  Also consider that pedals of this vintage were not disposable, they were intended to be serviced.   Consider servicing them to extend their life time.  "how to service a pedal?" could be a good on-topic question.

Comment: And the answers 100% reflect the shoping nature of the question. With links to shops that are likely to rot, not actually be offering the pedals now or in future, or be just advertising a particular seller.

Comment: To illustrate the point, at the moment the Velo Orange pedals are all sold out

Comment: @Criggie I had been considering this also, so thanks for the reassurance about servicing the pedal.

Answer (score 5):

MKS makes vintage style pedals that are available on Amazon.de

This one is a aluminum. A little nicer than the original steel.
MKS Pedale Sylvan Touring, Silber, 2 Stück
[image]

Another old style
MKS Pedale Sylvan Road, Silber
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the german equivalent of Craigslist, an online platform to buy and sell used items

https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/

There are plenty of old bicycles and related items, with some luck you can find someone having bicycle parts lots and they will ship them to your location.

Comment: How is this different from any othe bicycle secondhand shop?

Comment: @VladimirF Its not really an seconhand shop, its the german equivalent to craigslist.

Comment: The worse. You should not really answer with a link "this is a local version of a page where people offer old stuff, you might find it there if you are lucky". If it were a real shop, there would at least be the possibility of you knowing they stock such pedals.

Comment: I found it helpful and is currently my best option

Comment: I guess the answer was poorly written, but rather useful: the bicycle is of german breeding, it is very worthwhile to check the "online garage sales" type of sites. 

Yes, the OP may contact a bicycle shop in Germany, with pandemy and so on they may be used to online sales. However, the hassle of shipping internationally may be too much for a shop (with all the strings attached to a commercial transaction, the shops bear all the risk), while for a private may be easier (and usually without warranties, so the buyer bear the risk)